# Android external micro USB Wifi Antenna

Tags: android, usb, wifi, device

First of all, I want to understand if is possible plug an external micro USB WiFi antenna like [this](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/1951392207/New_Micro_USB_external_antenna_android_usb.jpg_350x350.jpg) to an android phone and drive it through application to communicate with another android device that have same antenna plugged.

I'm able to detect plugged external antenna in my application using USB Host API of android as specified [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) and establish an USB connection with it.

In this page there is also a sample that explains how to send commands to an external usb device sending data via connection like "1" "turn left", "2" "turn right".

How can I know what commands (methods/interface/api or data byte stream) I have to send to use device features?

I understand that there is the possibility that I'm saying a lot of stupid things !!! but be patient please!

I also read about [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) but i cant figure if it is the right way!

I have seen on youtube a Drone driven by an android phone with same antenna plugged through Andropilot application! see video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylMO_3R0ju4)

There is some guide or tutorial to point me to the right way?

Comment: If its a wifi antenna, its just going to create a wifi network.  Why not just use the built in wifi hotspot ability and skip the hardware step?

Comment: @GabeSechan: It's not a wifi antenna, it's a wifi adapter with its antenna. I assume the goal is to increase the range of the radio link, compared to the built-in adapter.

Comment: Yes the goal is to increase the range of the radio link!! In open space you can reach 300-500 metres guaranted depends on quality/strength of antenna used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like the [drone radio](https://store.3drobotics.com/products/3dr-radio) you probably saw, you would use the [Android Open Accessory protocol](http://source.android.com/accessories/) to talk to devices over USB.  You can prototype and experiment using boards like the Android ADK or the IOIO.  Here's a page comparing those boards that has more information: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371750

And here's a simple tutorial showing how to use the ADK to control LEDs via USB: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-ADK-LED-Lighting/